# Action Bar Back Button Crashes on WebView

Tags: android-studio, webview, crash, android-actionbar, back-button

I am currently implementing a back button action for navigating webview history. My webview has been working(including handling opening links within the webview). However, after adding the back button action it crashes whenever I try to use the back button. This is my Main Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
//Back Button Code
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(amapps.com.uhss.R.layout.activity_main);
     WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://uhsswordandshield.com/");
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);



}
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with the code. I believe it has to do with my
    WebView mWebView;
declaration before I initialize the webview. But I am not sure of any way to handle webview history navigation. Also, I am unsure of how to post my log cat and what to post so if someone could please tell me which part of the logcat I need to post that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
if((keyCode==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){

        if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                mWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Comment: Where would I put this

Comment: If it is out if the on create how do I declare mWebView or how do I make it a global variable

Comment: put this code in onKeyDown method instead your code.

Comment: Ok, but do I have to declare mWebView again

Comment: Or could you please just edit my code because I think that will be easier to understand.